# ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES when previewing in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os, google-chrome-arc

I am trying to download the excel file from my application that has around 1000 line of records. But I couldn't able to download. It throws an error: "**Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES** ". It throws a huge number of errors in the console. I checked with other browser as well but I am able to download from the Firefox browser. The issue is only in Chrome browser. But I want to run it in Chrome because my client only use Chrome Browser.

I tried by clearing cookies, reinstalling Chrome and still it is not working. My Chrome Version is 56.0.2924.76. I am using Java and Angular JS for this application.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you try to download a single Excel file you see this error? Are you trying to download anything else? It looks like this error pops up when you try to download more resources than Chrome can handle simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks Kayce for your response. Yes, I am trying to download the singe Excel file.  I am not trying to download anything except the text content in the Excel sheet but it has large amount of record(I can say 2000 rows of records). So can you please help me if there is a way to resolve this issue? How can we handle this?